# Inserting data to mysql, avoiding sql injection using python

Tags: python, mysql, sql-injection

where I am doing wrong? query runs successfully but no data store in database table

My block of code is

```
import pymysql                                                                                         
db = pymysql.connect(host='', user='', passwd='',db='')                     
cursor = db.cursor()                                                                                   
cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO Mention ( keyword, required, optional, excluded)                     
      VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)""",                                                                         
     [                                                                                                 
     ("Spam","fg","gtg","uu") ,                                                                        
     ("dd","fg","gtg","uu") ,                                                                          
     ("dd","fg","gtg","uu")                                                                            
     ])                                                                                                
print(cursor.fetchmany())
```

[image]

Comment: did you get any error? you says "no store data" because the print not return nothing or why?. I runned your code and the data is stored, but the print not returns nothing

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with SQL injection. You appear to be using the parameters properly. But you didn't commit the transaction, and pymysql does not commit implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

It is advised to pass the parameters into the execute function instead because they will be escaped automatically.

Try this:

```
insert_stmt = (
  "INSERT INTO Mention ( keyword, required, optional, excluded)                     
      VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
)
data = [                                                                                                 
     ("Spam","fg","gtg","uu") ,                                                                        
     ("dd","fg","gtg","uu") ,                                                                          
     ("dd","fg","gtg","uu")                                                                            
     ]
cursor.execute(insert_stmt, data)
```